# HTML: < link > tag should not fetch 1 same file more than once

Tags: javascript, html

I am including a .js file using < link > attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

i want to put a condition that it should not include more than once in a page.
how can i put such a condition in HTML only. If that is not possible using HTML only,then what are the other options i can use to put such condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not possible with HTML.
Use JavaScript.

```
// keep track of scripts
var scripts = { };

function includeOnce(s) {
  // if the script is not included before
  if (!(s in scripts)) {
    // add script
    var sc = document.createElement('script');
    sc.src = s;
    document.body.appendChild(sc);
    scripts[s] = 1;
  }
}
```

To include a script:

```
<script>{ include_once("script.js") }</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your script executes codes when loaded it may be sufficient to ensure your JS files are cached. Then in the worst case you're only sending an if-modified-since query which has a small overhead, especially if HTTP pipelining is supported.

Answer (score -1):

Create a global variable in your script.js file, something like :

```
var isIncluded = true;
```

And then include your script like so

```
<script>!window.isIncluded && document.write('<script src="script.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Comment: `isIncluded` isn't a global variable, and this would only work for a single script.